# jQuery Mobile, collapsible key-value grid: sizing header 50/50 with icon

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, user-interface, web, icons

I have a bunch of tabular/key-value data, of which I always show one item and the rest when the user clicks on the first, like [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9g3v/):

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3><div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Customer:</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">Mario's Plumbing</div></div></h3>
  <ul data-role="listview">
  <li><div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">Phone:</div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">1-800-MUS-ROOM</div></div></li>
  ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, when jQuery Mobile adds an icon to the header item ("Customer: Mario's Plumbing"), the value field, i.e. "Mario's Plumbing", doesn't align with the value fields in the <ul> list, i.e. "1-800-MUS-ROOM".

I think jQuery puts the icon side-by-side with the "Customer: Mario's Plumbing" box---this is compatible with what I see: the misalignment looks roughly like 100% of a button width for the key field and 50% of a button for the value field, which I would expect given my use of a ui-grid-a (which does a 50/50 split).  I would want the icon to be part of the left 50%, i.e. inside rather than beside that box.  Can I do that?  How?  It might be easy CSS and me being a CSS retard :)

Comment: check your tags, they're not closed properly

Comment: Please supply a working example of the problem, perhaps using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: There is still an unmatched `</a>` which is probably what @Th0rndike was alluding to

Comment: Code tweaked, jsFiddle added :-)

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/g9g3v/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the jQuery mobile element styles are not playing nicely together, in this case the [collapsible block](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html) and the [grid layout](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-grids.html) styles.

The collapsible block adds the icon and the style which pads the header.

```
.ui-btn-inner {
    padding:.6em 20px;
}
```

The additional rule, pads the left even more (to move the text away from the icon)

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-inner, .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-icon-left .ui-btn-inner {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

but this pushes all the header text left by 40px.

The only way I could find to correct the mismatch is to add an additional rule to move the second block to the left. By adding the following rule, the text lines up again.

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-inner .ui-grid-a .ui-block-b {
    margin-left:-10px;
}
```

It seems to work fine at different page zoom levels in my local Chrome browser testing but I have not tested on a mobile device.

**Edit:** Also, there is a typo in the example and the fiddle, you have `un-block-b` and not `ui-block-b` for *Mario's Plumbing*.